# asp.net core razor pages support for delete and put requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Recently, I read about request handling in asp.net core razor pages and it says that it supports `head` requests using the convention:

```
public void OnHead()
{
}
```

It worked perfectly. And then I also tried delete using the same convention.

```
public void OnDelete()
{
}
```

But when I send a delete request using postman, it returns a bad request (500). I'm not sure if i need to provide additional configurations to use delete requests. Any one could help me pls.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no `OnDelete`/`OnPut`. This is because Razor Pages are directly geared towards web views, i.e. pages displaying in a browser tab/window. There is no native way in a browser to send DELETE/PUT requests, so there's no reason to support them. Instead, such tasks are handled via an HTML form element, which would send via POST. As such, you would use `OnPost()` to handle it.

The docs recommend creating a new Razor Page for delete, with its own `OnGet` and `OnPost` methods, specifically geared to handling deletes. Alternatively, you may simply add an additional handler to an existing Razor Page in the form of `OnPost[Something]`. For a delete, that would likely be `OnPostDelete`, while for an update, you'd likely have `OnPostUpdate`. The name doesn't matter, except that you will need to pass it as a `handler` such as:

```
<form asp-page="Foo" asp-handler="Delete">
```

If you need to interact via a thin client (`HttpClient`, AJAX, Postman, etc.), then you should avoid Razor Pages altogether and stick with traditional controllers, which fully supports all HTTP verbs.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you have a markup like this:

```
<button type="submit" asp-page-handler="delete" 
        asp-route-id="@contact.Id">delete</button>
```

The correct method for delete would be `OnPostDelete` (or `OnPostDeleteAsync`).

So, could update to:

```
public void OnPostDelete(int id)
{
}
```

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#code-try-19) state:

> By convention, the name of the handler method is selected based on the
>   value of the handler parameter according to the scheme
>   `OnPost[handler]Async`

Further, the `Async` suffix is optional:

> The `Async` naming suffix is optional but is often used by convention
>   for asynchronous functions.

Answer (score 2):

This is an update for 2023.

You can easily utilize the DELETE verb of an Ajax request:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnDeleteAsync(int id)
{
    await _myService.DeleteUser(id);

    return new OkResult();
}
```

With jQuery it looks something like this:

```
<script>

$(".deletebtn").on("click", function (e) { 
    deleteUser($(this).data("id"));
});

const deleteUser = function (userId) {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'DELETE', // specify HTTP verb.
        url: '/account/users', // specify right path to your controller/razor page
        headers:
        {
            "RequestVerificationToken": "<get your token here>"
        },
        data: { id: userId },
        success: function () {
            window.location.href = "/account/users"; // reload page
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
};

</script>
<button class="deletebtn" data-id="123">Delete</button>
<button class="deletebtn" data-id="456">Delete</button>
<button class="deletebtn" data-id="1111">Delete</button>
```

Similarly the HTTP verbs GET, POST, PUT can also be utilized:

```
OnGet(), OnPost(), OnPut()
```

and their async equivalents

```
OnGetAsync(), OnPostAsync(), OnPutAsync()
```

Usage e.g.:

```
OnGetUsersAsync() // GET a list of Users async. 
OnPostUserAsync() // POST (add) a User async. 
OnPutUpdateMyUserAsync() // PUT (update) a user async
OnDeleteCoffeCup(id)  /// DELETE method sync.
```

In addition you can add your own experimental HTTP verbs. See e.g. here https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/adding-experimental-http-methods-to-aspnet-core