# How to call an endpoint with HttpDelete attribute in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

As usual we are using Http.ActionLink or 'a' tag with tag helpers to call an endpoint and they send Post request. How can I reach the api/models/5 [HttpDelete] by call from the view?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [asp.net core razor pages support for delete and put requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55602172/asp-net-core-razor-pages-support-for-delete-and-put-requests)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Browsers only support `HTTP GET` and `HTTP POST` verbs when using HTML. You can use other verbs (`DELETE`, `PUT` etc) from JavaScript however (via `fetch` or `XmlHttpRequest`).

Comment: I had exactly the same issue, when you remove HttpDelete attribute then it hits the Action as expected. You will be sending a GET request and do the DELETE logic in an Action. The best solution will be using ajax to do the DELETE request and use the HttpDelete attribute.