# Multiple forms in @foreach loop. How do I submit one asynchronously with javascript. C# core Razor

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core

Shopping cart with many items how to remove any item asynchronously with JavaScript this is my work so far. Can anyone improve on this?

your help would be greatly appreciated. Have a great day

Ok so this works if you remove items from the top of the list but fails if you remove items from some other place.

The problem seems to be that the form names are all the same "remove" without any indexing.

Problem is I'm not sure how to proceed with this.

```
document.forms['remove'].onsubmit = () => {
        let formData = new FormData(document.forms['remove']);
        fetch('/sales/cart?handler=RemoveItem', {
            method: 'post',
            body: new URLSearchParams(formData)

    })
        .then(() => {
                var url = "/sales/cart?handler=CartPartial";
                console.log(url)
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#exampleModal .modal-dialog").html(data);
                        $("#exampleModal").modal("show");
                        //alert('Posted using Fetch');
                    }
                });
            });
        return false;
    }

   
    <pre>
       @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
       {
          <form name="remove" method="post">
            <h4 class="text-left text-body">@item.Price.ToString("c")
            <button class="btn btn-sm" title="Trash"><i style="font-size:large" 
             class="text-warning icon-Trash"></i></button>
            </h4>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Id" name="cartId" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.Id" name="cartItemId" />
          </form>

       }
   </pre>

Update


----------
New markup
I added an index to the id and included an onclick event.


    <form method="post" id="@i" onclick="removeItem(this.id)">
    <button class="btn btn-sm" title="Trash">Item One</button>
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Id" name="cartId" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.Id" name="cartItemId" />
    </form>


and create a new function that captured the form id including it in a constant.

    <script>
    function removeItem(formId) {
        const form = document.getElementById(formId);
        form.onsubmit = () => {
            let formData = new FormData(form);
            fetch('/sales/cart?handler=RemoveItem', {
                method: 'post',
                body: new URLSearchParams(formData)
            })
                .then(() => {
                    var url = "/sales/cart?handler=CartPartial";
                    console.log(url)
                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        success: function (data) {
                            $("#exampleModal .modal-dialog").html(data);
                            $("#exampleModal").modal("show");
                            //alert('Posted using Fetch');
                        }
                    });
                });
            return false;
        }
    }
    </script>




If anybody can improve on this please post it here.
Thanks.


Updates code behind Cart.cshtml.cs

    using System;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Malawby.Models;
    using Malawby.Services.Interfaces;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

    namespace Malawby.Pages.Sales
    {
    public class CartModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ICartRepository _cartRepository;
        public CartModel(ICartRepository cartRepository)
        {
            _cartRepository = cartRepository ?? throw new 
        ArgumentNullException(nameof(cartRepository));
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Cart Cart { get; set; } = new Cart();

        public const string SessionKeyName = "_Name";
        public string SessionInfo_Name { get; private set; }

        public void OnGetAsync()
        {

        }
        public async Task<PartialViewResult> OnGetCartPartialAsync()
        {
            var userName = GetUserName();
            if (userName != null)
            {
                Cart = await _cartRepository.GetCartByUserName(userName);
            }
            return Partial("_ToCart", model: Cart);
        }
        private string GetUserName()
        {
            return HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyName);
        }
        public async Task OnPostRemoveItemAsync(int cartId, int cartItemId)
        {
            await _cartRepository.RemoveItem(cartId, cartItemId);                   
        }
        }
        }

Update 2

This is the modified code I used. This is the error in the console.
XML Parsing Error: no root element found Location: localhost:44331/sales/cart?handler=RemoveItem Line Number 1, Column 1
There is no error on the page just nothing happens on the click of the trash can.

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function removeItem(cartItemId, cardId) {
            var removeUrl = "/sales/cart?handler=RemoveItem";
            $.post(removeUrl,
                {
                    cartItemId: cartItemId,
                    cardId: cardId
                })
                .done(function (data) {
                    alert(data); //usually return true or false if true 
     remove card
                    $('#card_' + cardId).remove();
                });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: you can do it without adding multiple form just add onclick="removeItem(this.id) to the button and call your delete api

Comment: and I think no need to call '/sales/cart?handler=CartPartial' after deleting just remove the card by using jquery or javascript

Comment: That's interesting I shall give it a go.

Comment: Hmm your suggestion user1150331 did not seem to work. Maybe I misunderstood. I removed  from the "then" down but it just threw a bad page return. No matter it is working fine as is. Thanks anyway.

Comment: will then if you still interested please update the question and add controller code to check it

Comment: Ok I will do so. This project is in C# and asp.net core 5. There are no controllers as such but a code behind page cshtml.cs for each cshtml page. I'm assuming you are well versed  with .net core 5. Look forward to your input. Thank you.

Comment: BTW - user1150331 you may like to see my website malawby.com Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with asp.net core, but I will show how I usually do it without focusing on syntax.

first on the view no need to add multiple form but should use card id as index and delete button sent selected index like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
       {
          <div id="card_@item.cardId">
            <h4 class="text-left text-body">@item.Price.ToString("c")
            <button class="btn btn-sm" onclick="removeItem('@item.cardId') title="Trash"><i style="font-size:large" 
             class="text-warning icon-Trash"></i></button>
            </h4>
          </div>

       }
```

then the script function will call remove api and remove selected card with no need to re-render the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function removeItem(cardId) {
        var removeUrl = "your apiUrl";
        $.post( "removeUrl", { cardId: cardId })
              .done(function( data ) {
                  alert( data ); //usually return true or false if true remove card
                  $('#card_'+ cardId).remove();
         });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Well! Yes, this not what I expected, I am sure it will work well. I shall give it a go. Thank you for your time, Well done.

Comment: Sorry to report I ran into an error with your code. XML Parsing Error: no root element found Location: https://localhost:44331/sales/cart?handler=RemoveItem
Line Number 1, Column 1:

Comment: I would like to help you, please add more details for the error

Comment: Ok Thank you. I used your code with some modification (see above) I tested this in FireFox and Chrome browsers. I have Googled the error and found may instances of this problem but in the end I was unable to resolve it. I modified the code in different ways but nothing worked. Is there anything specific you need to know. I'm a little lost.

Comment: I found this post about how delete works on asp razor page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55602172/asp-net-core-razor-pages-support-for-delete-and-put-requests

Comment: I didn't know that on razor pages the post and delete api is not working like the normal controller. so sorry my answer will not be useful for you

Comment: There is no need to be apologetic as the exercise has given me food for thought. I will play around with it in the future. Thank you for your gracious help.